# Finding missing dog using Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, date

I know this isn't the place to ask, but I need help to find my dog. I was wondering if there was anyway to possible track which way he left or what happened to him. He has severe separation anxiety and I'm afraid he's terrified and alone. He went missing on 11/20/2021 and Google Earth doesn't have that current of a date for me.

Is there anyway to view that date?

Comment: Even if you got extremely lucky, and a satellite was overhead just when you needed it to be, even 1-foot imagery would not be able to discern a dog from orbit. That same satellite would not pass overhead again for several weeks, and there's little chance the right location would be imaged again so quickly. I'm sorry, but GIS SE cannot help you.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way google earth, or any online map platform, can be used to find a missing dog.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you lost your dog. I just lost one recently so I feel your pain. It's too late now, but I would highly recommend getting a GPS tracking collar if you have other dogs, or plan to get dogs in the future. We personally use a brand called Fi, which I think is the best option in the USA. There are lots of other options out there.